# Akka Actor Setup: In Main method or in 'Manager' class?

Tags: scala, akka

Does anyone have any advice about how the creation of a large number of akka actors should be managed?

My new middleware project currently contains about 10 actors, but over time this will inevitably grow to a high number. I'm creating all my actors in my `main` function, but this could potentially get out of control as the system grows, with the function spanning an entire screen.

I could of course move all the actor creation into a function in a separate class, though this doesn't really solve the problem as such.

I'm not sure if there are any patterns available to help manage this setup procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally one should have but a few top-level Actors (i.e. ones that are created by using system.actorOf). This is because you get a very poor fault-tolerance if all Actors are just as likely to ruin things for the others. So what you should do is to think about how you want failure to be contained in your application and then create actors as children of other actors using context.actorOf.

Comment: Does using context.actorOf directly make it difficult to mock these actors when writing unit tests? I've got a couple of unit tests where I use TestProbes to ensure messages are forwarded correctly. To facilitate this I have actorRef arguments in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the relationship of the actors. If they have no parent/child relationship to each other it doen't really matter where you start them. If they have such a relationship, you should start your actors inside their parents, because you have to use the `context` of the parent actor to create another actor as its child.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question without knowing more about the nature of the actors you are creating. For example, if you can logically group your actors, I'd do something like this:

```
def initialize() = {

    // Initialize Misc actors
    val foo = FooActor()
    val bar = BarActor()

    initializeActorsThatDoStuff()
    initializeActorsThatDoOtherStuff()

}
```

If they have a parent/child relationship you should do as @drexin suggests.

---

**Edit:** Almost forgot: I you are creating multiple actors of the same type with different parameters, I'd of course use a loop and not copy and paste, e.g.

```
def initializeLotsOfActors(num:Int) =
    for(i <- 0 to num) new ActorThatTakesAnInt(i);
```

(because nobody likes copy and paste :D)

Comment: Note, that in Akka actors are not created with `new`.

Comment: Shame on me :) haven't really written Scala in some time.

Comment: My use case is described in general terms in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419335/managing-2-connections-in-scala-esque-fashion

I have actors which help to manage connections with a vendor API. I imagine I will also have a series of actors which will deal with individual message types received from the API, and pub/sub actors which relay information to different IT systems within our organisation. 

Let me know if I still need to be a bit clearer with the context.